# Is this structure acceptable: "After D comes E."

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality-in-context, poetry

**"After D comes E."**

I know that we don't use this structure very often but I see such structures (the subject is preceeded by the verb (...comes E instead of ...E comes), which is completely the opposite of what we are taught at school.

If this structure is not specific to some special usage-like poetry or scientific facts-, and is acceptable in contemporary English, can I also apply it to other everyday conversations without sounding weird or funny, eg telling about something in the past.

For instance if I mention about who arrived first and the last in the workplace yesterday;

**"After the accountant, came the secretary and then came the boss"**.

Can I invert the verb and the subject of a sentence like this in formal or contemporary english?

Comment: This sounds natural to me (without the second came) : After the accountant, came the secretary and then the boss.

Comment: Your *After the accountant, came the secretary and then came the boss* sounds like it's something from a children's story book for *very* advanced children! I'd advise you to simply accept this kind of highly stylised inversion *when you encounter it from native Anglophones*. But don't copy it in your own writing, and *certainly* don't  use it in normal speech! It's ***literary / poetic***.